# Why is a file unplayable in Windows Media Player?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mp4, windows-media-player, x264

I have written some code to generate a MP4 video. This is a simplified version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <unistd.h>

extern "C"
{
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavutil/frame.h"
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavutil/imgutils.h"
}
using namespace std;

const int output_width = 180;
const int output_height = 320;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    AVCodec *output_avc = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264");
    if (!output_avc)
        abort();
    AVCodecContext *output_cc = avcodec_alloc_context3(output_avc);
    if (!output_cc)
        abort();

    output_cc->time_base.num = output_cc->time_base.den = 1;
    output_cc->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    output_cc->width = output_width;
    output_cc->height = output_height;

    if (avcodec_is_open(output_cc) == 0)
    {
        if (avcodec_open2(output_cc, output_avc, 0) < 0)
            abort();
    }

    string outf = "res.mp4";
    AVFormatContext *output_ctx;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&output_ctx, NULL, NULL, outf.c_str());
    AVStream *out_stream = avformat_new_stream(output_ctx, 0);
    out_stream->codecpar->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    out_stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    out_stream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
    out_stream->codecpar->width = output_width;
    out_stream->codecpar->height = output_height;
    out_stream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    av_dump_format(output_ctx, 0, outf.c_str(), 1);
    if (!(output_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        if (avio_open(&output_ctx->pb, outf.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0)
            abort();
    }
    if (avformat_write_header(output_ctx, NULL) < 0)
        abort();

    AVPacket packet;
    AVFrame *frame;
    int fileCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        frame = av_frame_alloc();
        frame->width = output_width;
        frame->height = output_height;
        frame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
        if (av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, frame->width, frame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 32) < 0)
            abort();
        frame->pts = 60000 * i;
        frame->pkt_dts = 60000 * i;
        if (avcodec_send_frame(output_cc, frame) < 0)
            abort();
        av_frame_free(&frame);

        av_new_packet(&packet, 0);
        while (avcodec_receive_packet(output_cc, &packet) >= 0)
        {
            packet.pos = -1;
            packet.dts = 4500 * fileCount;
            packet.pts = 4500 * fileCount;
            packet.duration = 4500;
            av_write_frame(output_ctx, &packet);
            av_packet_unref(&packet);
            av_new_packet(&packet, 0);
            fileCount++;
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }
    avcodec_free_context(&output_cc);

    av_write_trailer(output_ctx);
    if (output_ctx && !(output_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_close(output_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(output_ctx);
}
```

Then, I compiled it (with `g++ encode.cpp -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -g` and libraries are installed via Ubuntu 20.04 apt) and run it. This is the MP4 file I get (2872 bytes, base64 encoded):

```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```

And I try to play it in Media Player in Windows 11. It can not play at all and fails with a 0xC00D36C4 error.

Later I compiled and run the same code in Ubuntu 22.04. This time I got a 3161 byte file (base64 encoded) which can be correctly played in Media Player:

```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```

Answer (score 1):

The unplayable file is missing AVC config box in the MP4.

Add

```
output_cc->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
```

before opening the codec.